# how to handle multiple request to update table simultaneously

Tags: mysql, concurrency, webserver, acid

i am designing an ticket booking system for a circus.suppose there are 1 seat left and there are 4 users who request simultaneously to reserve the ticket.how to handle such type of cases in mysql or webserver.

Comment: You would need to have a table that acts as a request for seats table. Use a stored procedure maybe.

Then you must have a current_timestamp on the createddatetime column in that request, then you can simply order on CreatedDateTime ASC for that seat_id. Your question is to broad, you dont even have any code so its hard to begin to help.

Comment: MySQL transactions. Read about them. Try some things.

Comment: @KayNelson You're overthinking. If you do store `seat_id` then you can just plant a `UNIQUE` index on `(show_id,seat_id)` to prevent the double booking.

Comment: @Jakub that also works. In consideration if there is a que and the first one doesnt complete the booking. But i agree with you.